# XSL-FOでページごとにレイアウトを自動変更したい

Tags: xsl, xsl-fo

XSL-FOで柱やノンブルの位置をページごとに変更したいと考えています。
XSL-FOではどのように記述すればページごとにレイアウトを変更することができるでしょうか？
例えば、奇数ページは柱やノンブルを左寄せ、偶数ページは右寄せにできればと思います。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XSL-FOでは、各ページのレイアウトの設定は、fo:layout-master-set で行います．
この中で、左ページ用のレイアウト、右ページ用レイアウトを、fo:simple-page-master で定義します．
例えば以下のようになります．

```
<fo:layout-master-set>
  <fo:simple-page-master master-name="odd-pagemaster">
    :
  <fo:simple-page-master>
  <fo:simple-page-master master-name="odd-pagemaster">
    :
  <fo:simple-page-master>
</fo:layout-master-set>
```

このように定義したレイアウトをどのように配置するかを、
fo:page-sequence-master で設定します．
例えば以下のようになります．

```
<fo:page-sequence-master master-name="PageMaster">
 <fo:repeatable-page-master-alternatives>
   <fo:conditional-page-master-reference master-reference="odd-pagemaster" odd-or-even="even"/>
   <fo:conditional-page-master-reference master-reference="odd-pagemaster" odd-or-even="odd"/>
   </fo:repeatable-page-master-alternatives>
```

この 
fo:conditional-page-master-reference の odd-or-evenに "even"を指定すると偶数ページに、
"odd"を指定すると奇数ページに、それぞれ指定された master-reference のレイアウトが適用されます．

> 例えば、奇数ページは柱やノンブルを左寄せ、偶数ページは右寄せにできればと思います。

一般的に、柱やノンブルのような各ページに共通するような内容は、ページのヘッダやフッタに配置します．
前述の方法で奇数ページ、偶数ページの切り替えはできるようになりますので、それぞれのページのfo:simple-page-masterの中で定義したヘッダ、フッタの領域の出力時に
右寄せ、左寄せなどを指定します．
例えば、

```
  <fo:simple-page-master master-name="odd-pagemaster">
   <fo:region-after region-name="afterLeft" extent="10.0mm" ...
```

と指定した奇数ページのページマスタのフッタ領域の出力時に

```
  <fo:page-sequence...>
    <fo:static-content flow-name="afterLeft">
     <fo:block text-align="end">
       <fo:inline>
          <fo:page-number/>
       </fo:inline>
     </fo:block>
   </fo:static-content>
    :
```

とノンブルに text-align="end"と指定すれば、end側に揃えられます．